# Junit Assertion Error for ArrayList and Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, junit

I have method which returns ArrayList of object as below -

```
public <Range> getAllRanges(List<Range> ranges){
  //Some business logic
  ....
  List<Range> resultRanges = new ArrayList<>();
  .....
  return resultRanges;
}
```

I am writing Junit for this as -

```
@Test
public void someInputTest() {
    final List<Range> ranges = Arrays.asList(new Range(1, 3), new Range(2, 4));
    final List<Range> actual = myCalss.getAllRanges(ranges);
    final List<Range> expected = Arrays.asList(new Range(1, 4));
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

but I am getting Assertion Error like -

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList<[(1, 4)]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[(1, 4)]>
....
```

After that I tried below code in test -

```
@Test
public void someInputTest() {
    final List<Range> ranges = Arrays.asList(new Range(1, 3), new Range(2, 4));
    final List<Range> actual = myCalss.getAllRanges(ranges);
    final List<Range> expected = new ArrayList<>();
    expected.add(new Range(1, 4));
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

but after that I am getting -

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.ArrayList<[(1, 4)]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[(1, 4)]>
...
```

Now expected and actual are bot same but still assertion error. What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: This is basic Java. You are comparing two different Objects. Of course they are not equal... Add dependency for Hamcrest library, and add assertion like: assertThat(list1, containsInAnyOrder(list2.toArray()));

Comment: In Range have you implemented an equals method?

Comment: Two lists are equal if their corresponding elements are equal (and have the same length), so `assertEquals` is perfectly fine for testing two lists for equality. Make sure you have (correctly) implemented the `equals` method for `Range` class. E.g make sure this assertion passes: `assertEquals(new Range(1, 4), new Range(1, 4))`

Comment: Thank you. I have override equals method and it is working.

Answer (score 5):

Weirdly enough, `Arrays.asList` hasn't overridden `equals`, and thus even if it contains the same elements as another list of type `ArrayList`, they will not be compared as equal.

One solution is to wrap it into an `ArrayList`:

```
assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...)), myArrayList);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.You should add in your class , which used in list, equals and hashcode . After that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Equals and Hashcode methods in the object which is being used in Arraylist will surely help in the case of assertEquals for arraylists of user defined objects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way: just simply add `@EqualsAndHashCode` on your Range class.
`@EqualsAndHashCode` is provided by Project Lombok and generates hashCode and equals implementations from the fields of your object.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Range {
   private int x;
   // ...
}
```

And the following assertion works well in JUnit  4.13.1

```
Assert.assertEquals(expectedArrayList, actualArrayList);
```

https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode